# Getting this error when creating a yaml file in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s

Getting this error kindly give the solution and kindly see the attached screenshot[error[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5crnR.png)

Comment: can you share your yaml? I think there are some indentation issue with yaml

Comment: Add error logs instead of screenshot

Comment: If you could please attach the yaml file along with the error, it's an inappropriate question with invalid details.

Answer (score 1):

This means kubernetes is expecting value of an attribute in the yaml to be set to a map object. Your yaml currently has the value set to a string.

A map object will be something like below for the labels attribute.

```
"metadata": {
  "labels": {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2"
  }
}
```

Please have a look here for expected attribute types: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rpc/k8s.io.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1#k8s.io.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta